# Async update to Select is not applying selected attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have a directive that encapsulates a select drop down that gets it's data from a async web request. Upon the web request completing, I update the variable that the select ng-model is bound to, and update the scope via a scope.$apply(). This update is wrapped up in a setTimeout due to the async nature of the web request, but in my provided jsFiddle i've emulated this call by virtue of a slight delay on the setTimeout.

The issue is as follows: whilst everything works as expected, if you inspect the select element, done of the options have the 'selected' attribute, which I rely on for unit testing. If i get rid of the setTimeout and simply update the model with

```
            scope.currentModel = scope.datalist[_.findIndex(scope.datalist, {
                'code': scope.ngModel
            })];

            scope.$apply();
```

Then the correct option gets the

> selected="selected"

attribute I can use for my unit tests. So my question is, why, when I use setTimeout, does the model get updated and reflected in the browser, but the selected option not get the selected attribute? This seems to happen in both Safari and Chrome for Mac, not tested on Windows. [jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc576az/5/)